# Getting error for nesting structure in class

Tags: c++

i am having error when i nest a structure inside a class

This is the header file

```
class chord
{
  public:
    struct Node
    {
      void del(string, chord&);
      void insert(string, chord&);
    };
    map<int, Node>& getNodeList(); # line 44
}
```

This is the error message:

```
44|error: candidate is: std::map<int, chord::Node>& chord::getNodeList()|
```

This is the .ccp file

```
map<int, Node>& chord::getNodeList() # line 34
{
  return Node_List;
}
```

When i try to compile i get the following error

```
main.cpp|34|error: 'Node' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp|34|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
main.cpp|34|error: template argument 4 is invalid|
main.cpp|34|error: prototype for 'int& chord::getNodeList()' does not match any in class 'chord'|
```

When i change to the following type, i get this error

```
|35|error: invalid use of non-static data member 'chord::node'|
|44|error: from this location|

class chord
{
  public:
    struct Node
    {
      void del(string, chord&);
      void insert(string, chord&);
    }node;
    map<int, node>& getNodeList();
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: add a member of type `Node_List` to your `chord` class and operate with that object, not a type as you doing now

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

`Node` is defined inside `chord`, so when the it sees `map<int, Node>` in your .cpp file, it doesn't find a `Node`. Put `chord::` in front of it there, too.

```
map<int, chord::Node>& chord::getNodeList()
```

In your second code snippet, you declare a member object of type `Node` named `node`, and then try to use it as a template type parameter. You wanted the syntax in your first snippet.